# Share data between components

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, angular5, angular4-forms, angular4-router

I have a form with 3 interfaces , im using angular 5 i want to save the object partenire in the end. i used a parent component that conatin 3 components ( interfces 1,2,3) , how can i share the data betwenn the childs compnet then send it to the parent and save it to database ??

[image: premier interface d'inscription]

[image: deuxieme interface d'inscription]

[image: troisieme interface]

Comment: Please use a spellchecker when writing posts.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to create another component called `CommonService`, inside this service, you can implement a couple of methods (or observables). And afterwards this service can be injected into all your three components mentioned above.

```

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class CommonService {
    data;
    fetchData() { http.get().subscribe(res => this.data = res;} }
}

...
export class FeaturePageComponent {
    constructor(private commonService: CommonService) {
        this.commonService.fetchData();
    }
```

```